# How do i limit time to one hour in datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker

I have the following JavaScript code that uses of a `StartDate` & `EndDate` field.

What this code does is to restrict the dates on the `EndDate` field to the day you have chosen in the `StartDate` field.

What I am trying to do is to restrict time as well, for example the "datetimepicker" consists of a drop-down with Hours.

How do I restrict the `EndDate` field to one hour(according to the hour I have chosen from the `StartDate` field plus one) and maybe disable the rest of available hours?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
             var dates = $('#StartDate, #EndDate').datetimepicker({
                 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                 hourMin: 9,
                 hourMax: 17,
                 minDate: '1',
                 maxDate: null,
                 controlType: 'select',
                 timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
                 beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
                 firstDay: 1,
                 changeFirstDay: false,
                 onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                     var option = this.id == "StartDate" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                         instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
                         date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                             instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                             $.datetimepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                             selectedDate, instance.settings);
                     var edate;
                     var otherOption;
                     var d;                

                     if (option == "minDate") {
                         otherOption = "maxDate";   

                         d = date.getDate() + 0;                               
                     }

                     else if (option == "maxDate") {
                         otherOption = "minDate";   

                         d = date.getDate() - 0;                           
                     }

                     var m = date.getMonth();
                     var y = date.getFullYear();
                     edate = new Date(y, m, d);

                     dates.not(this).datetimepicker("option", option, date);
                     dates.not(this).datetimepicker("option", otherOption, edate);
                 }
             });
         });
```